# A few questions about how to build a program that uses a military authentication table?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What data structure array would you use to store an authentication table and have the user use a `Scanner` input to get certain data from the table. Such as, if the user types in *"delta three"* the program should respond with *"romeo four"* and authenticate it.

Questions:

1. What data structure should I use? `ArrayList` maybe?
2. How to give the data structure the dimensions of the authentication table? I assume I can use an index and put a number to represent the rows and columns.
3. How to make the objects that fill the table have no duplicates otherwise it will need to be regenerated?
4. How would I generate a new table?
5. So what sort of Java imports do I need and are there already built-in functions in Java/Netbeans that can help me out?

Yes, this seems like a lot but I struggle with this sort of things and need expert help.

If you need an example of the authentication table. Here is an example:

```
public class AuthenticationTable 
{ //Start of class method.

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { //Start of main method
        String [] [] Table = {{"E3","H5","R9","W8","S1"},
                              {"Z9","P5","K8","X5","I9"},
                              {"B2","F7","L2","M4","H3"},
                              {"J7","A7","N2","R6","V4"},
                              {"O9","W3","E8","U4","E8"}};

        System.out.println(Table[2][1]);
        System.out.println(Table[4][0]);

    } //End of main method
}//End of class method
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question sounds a lot like homework, so I'll try to simply point you in the right direction:

1. Take a look at the [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). You could store what the user will provide as key and the respective authentication as value.
2. The `HashMap` is a key value structure, thus you could store the request-expected response as so.
3. The keys of `HashMap` structures *must* be unique. So you will not have any duplicates. You could also use the `containsKey` method to see if a key already exists.
4. Given your example,

> Such as, if the user types in "delta three" the program should respond
>   with "romeo four" and authenticate it.

You could do something like so:

```
Map<String, String> authTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
authTable.put("D3", "R4");
...

String userInput = "D3";
System.out.println(authTable.get(userInput));   //This should yield R4, assuming that it exists.
```

As a side note, one usually keeps sensitive information stored somewhere else and does not ship the authentication table with the product since that would be a security risk. You could layer your code in such a way that one part pretends to send a request for authentication.

EDIT:

```
public class AuthenticationProvider {
    private Map<String, String> authTable;

    public AuthenticationProvider()
    {
        this.authTable = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String authenticate(String input)
    {
        return this.authTable.get(input);
    }

    public void addAuthentication(String source, String expected)
    {
        if(!this.authTable.containsKey(source))
            this.authTable.put(source, expected);
    }
}
```

.....

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    AuthenticationProvider authProvider = new AuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.addAuthentication("D3", "R4");

    System.out.print("The co-ordinates that your after: ");
    String userInput = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print(authProvider.authenticate(userInput));
```

Comment: Thanks @npinti for responding. So how does one create or use a hashmap as I haven't used one before. Is it simple?

Comment: The military think is an example of what the authentication table is used for as they use it to make sure that the area is clear in combat. Also would I need to create a java class that contains the getters, setters and the objects details?

Comment: @JacobFellows: Yes I understood your point, which is why I included it as a side note. Personally, I would create a new class, call it `AuthenticationProvider` or something like that which provides method to authenticate the calls you are given without exposing the hash map itself. This should expose you to 2 principles: Single Responsability and Encapsulation. If you want to take it a notch further, you could also take a look at how to make your `AuthenticationProvider` a singleton, which would expose you to some design patterns, but that might be beyond this assignment.

Comment: So if I create a class and link it to the main class it should allow me to keep certain details save. Also I tried making a version of the example you put above in Netbeans and this is what I have so far. 'public static void main(String[] args) { Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Map<String, String> authTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
authTable.put("D3", "R4");System.out.print("The co-ordinates that your after: ");scan.next();System.out.print(authTable.remove(scan)); }' the code allows the user to enter text but not return the variable R4. So I am going to create class for getters.

Comment: @JacobFellows: Technically, if you decouple the hash map from your class and place it in another class it would make it easier to change how would you would go about to get the data. I'll update my answer shortly to provide a quick working example.